# in linux using bash how can I split a text file based on percentage

Tags: linux, bash

I have a problem where I need to split files based on some arbitrary percentage.

If I have 100 lines I need to have the file split by a 70 % / 30 %.

The split program in linux does not give me the functionality I am looking for.

It would be nice to have simple function that can an arbitrary number of splits.

Comment: You tagged this question with [bash]. Is there a specific reason you want to use this specific shell and not just any program ?

Comment: You give a nice answer [below](http://superuser.com/a/904612/257269)... BTW  you mean 70% in number of lines. It can be interesting  70% in size too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created this simple function that does exactly what I want it to do.

```
# $1 percentage as a decimal fraction; e.g., 0.75 = 75% 
# increase decimal points to get more accurate rounding 0.755
# $2 input file
# $3 output file top percentage
# $4 output file bottom percentage
# e.g., 70% split = 70% top + 30% bottom = 100%
function file_prec_split () {

    TOTAL=$(wc -l $2 | cut -d" " -f 1)
    TOPPERC=`echo "scale=0; ${TOTAL} * $(printf %.2f $1)" | bc -l | cut -d"." -f 1`

    head -n $TOPPERC $2 > $3
    tail -n +$TOPPERC $2 > $4

}


echo "`seq 1 100`" > 1to100.txt
file_prec_split 0.30 1to100.txt 30top.txt 70bot.txt
```

If you would like to do some more complex splits like 
40% / 20% / 40%,
then you can run the function multiple times.
You need to group and then run the splits. 
Combine the first 40% and 20% into 60%.
Run 60% / 40% first and then 40% / 20%.

You might need to do some simple math to figure out how this split should be calculated.

60 % (40 % / 20 %) needs to be normalised to 100% 
Here is how I calculated this split

> 0.4/0.6 = .66
>   0.2/0.6 = .33

(60 % / 40%)

```
file_prec_split 0.60 1to100.txt 60top.txt 40bot.txt
```

(40% / 20 %) = 60 %

> 0.4/0.6 = .66

```
file_prec_split 0.66 60top.txt 40top.txt 20mid.txt
```

I found the following helpful when doing the calculations in Linux. The extra decimal places help with the rounding to be more accurate when doing the split.

```
SUP_PERCENT=$(printf %.2f $(echo "scale=4; 0.4/0.6" | bc -l))
file_prec_split $SUP_PERCENT 60top.txt 40top.txt 20top.txt
```

Comment: `SUP_PERCENT=$(printf %.2f $(echo "scale=4; 0.4/0.6" | bc -l))`
I found the following helpful when doing the calculations in Linux

Comment: (1) It’s generally a good idea in shell scripts to quote all variables and parameters (in double quotes); e.g., `"$2"` and `"$TOPPERC"`.  (See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4899/23408 "To quote or not to quote") and [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/23408 "Security implications of not quoting a variable in bash").)  The way you have it now, your function will fail if any of the filenames contain spaces (e.g., `file_prec_split 0.50 "my chores.txt" "do today.txt" "do tomorrow.txt"`) or other special non-alphanumeric characters.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d)  … (2) The fact that `wc` outputs its argument (the filename) even if there’s only one is often annoying.  (IMNSHO, there should be an option to suppress that, analogous to `grep`’s `-h`, a.k.a. `--no-filename`.)  A simple trick to prevent that behavior is to give the file as standard input (e.g., `wc -l < "$2"`), so it won’t _know_ the filename.  (3) I’m glad to see that you know about the `$(…)` form of command substitution.  [Many people believe that it’s preferable over `\`…\``](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/23408 "Difference between $(stuff) and \`stuff\`"),  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d)  … and it nests cleanly; so, for example, you could say `TOPPERC=$(echo …)`, even though the interior command already contains a command substitution (`$(printf …)`).  (4) You don’t need the curly braces in `${TOTAL}`.  You would need them if, for example, you wanted to multiply by 100 the fast way by saying `${TOTAL}00`, so, if `$TOTAL` were `17`, you would want to get `1700`.  A simple `$TOTAL00` would fail because it would look for a variable called `TOTAL00` (which is a valid name).  Note that you don’t need to (and shouldn’t) say `"$TOTAL"` here, because   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d)  … it’s already in quotes (`echo "…"`).  (5) Why do you say `$(printf %.2f $1)`?  If `$1` is an integer multiple of `.1` (e.g., `.4`), this will just append a `0` (and prepend one, also, if applicable), yielding `0.40`, which is equivalent to what you already had.  But if `$1` has more than two decimal digits, this will round it to two places.  For example, `.595` and `.60499` will both come out as `0.60`.  This could be significant if the file has more than a hundred lines, and it means that your “increase decimal points to get more accurate rounding” comment is wrong.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d)  … (6) It’s a good idea to get into the habit of quoting `printf` format strings (e.g., `$(printf "%.2f" "$1")`, although it doesn’t make a difference in this simple case.  (7) You don’t need to specify the `-l` option to `bc` to do simple math like this (although it doesn’t hurt).  (8) Your command to create the test file is unnecessarily complicated; `seq 1 100 > 1to100.txt` is good enough.  Although, again, if you really needed to use command substitution, I would recommend that you use `$(…)` instead of `\`…\``.